# Dynamic javascript variables

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic-variables

I would like to dynamically generate an integer (in the below case either 100 or 500) and use it to access separate arrays. In a later step (not part of the code below) I would also like to access different parts of those arrays in the same manner ("message 1, 2 or 3").

For this proof of concept I did not dynamically generate an integer, but I just set it to 100.

I then tried to use `eval()` to dynamically generate the array name consisting of "warning" and 100, but it is not working properly.

This is my code:

```
// two arrays are defined, warning100 and warning500
var warning100 = [
    { "message1":"Ok, go ahead and start typing!" },
    { "message2":"Keep going!" },
    { "message3":"You can do it!" }
];

var warning500 = [
    { "message1":"Slow down..." },
    { "message2":"That's it!" },
    { "message3":"Maximum reached." }
];

// set i to 100 and h to 1 for testing purposes, will be random integers in the final version
var i = 100;
var h = 2;
// create variable names as a combination of a string and i or h
// those variables will be used to access one of the arrays from above and one of the messages;
eval("var warningNumber = warning" + i + ";");
eval("var messageNumber = message" + h + ";");

/* alternative code for creating the two variable values
var warningNumber = "warning" + i;
var messageNumber = "message" + h;
*/

// the variable warningNumber from above is now used again to access the array warning100
// the varaible messageNumber is used to access one of the messages
// within that array message1 should be displayed
// create variable to be used in the document.write below
var warning = warningNumber[0].messageNumber;

// should alert "Ok, go ahead and start typing!"    
alert(warning);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make each set of warnings part of a warningNumber object? That way you could do

```
var warnings = {100: { 1:"Ok, go ahead and start typing!",
                       2:"Keep going!",
                       3:"You can do it!"
                     },
                500: { 1:"Slow down...",
                       2:"That's it!",
                       3:"Maximum reached."
                     }
               };
alert(warnings[i][h]);
```

That way all the eval doesn't even has to be done.

Comment: other than the horrific whitespace, this is the best answer. +1

Comment: thanks, awesome! i've been trying to wrap my head around how to create it using json, but i'm new to js and all that, so i need to learn a lot more. would you be so nice and explain why my initial code failed? or could it have worked somehow? actually, it kind of did, but it could only show "message1" and not 2 and 3...

Comment: i also tried to +1 your answer, but now it's at 0. don't know why. it told me that i don't have enough reputation yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap it in an object?

```
var dynamicHolder = {};
var i = 100;
var h = 2;
dynamicHolder["warningNumber"] = "warning" + i;
dynamicHolder["messageNumber"] = "message" + h;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var warnings = {

    warning100: {
        "message1":"Ok, go ahead and start typing!",
        "message2":"Keep going!",
        "message3":"You can do it!"
    },
    warning500: {
        "message1":"Slow down...",
        "message2":"That's it!",
        "message3":"Maximum reached."
    }
}

var i = 100;
console.log( warnings["warning" + i] );
i += 400;
console.log( warnings["warning" + i] );

console.log( warnings["warning" + i ]["message1"] );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qRHBP/)

Comment: ok, thanks, but i'm a javascript newbie, sorry :/ i would need to access both the arrays and the "messages" separately. what will your code give as an output? if i change the console.log to an alert it won't do anything...

Comment: I updated it :) You can get the msgs object or an individual msg.

Comment: @EricG downvoting every competing answer eh?

Comment: lol yeah some ass downvoted me ! Figured it was a competitor xD